# which color to use to have inverted darkmode swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, ios-darkmode

Im building a calculator and am in the process of adding dark mode support, so I changed all of my colors to be system colors so that they change when dark mode is activated on iOS for my background for example I use System background color which is white in light mode in black in dark mode.. but to display the text, I need exactly the opposite, the font has to be white in dark mode and black in light mode.. since im doing it in the storyboard I can't just set it to a color via component.color =... (,can I?) , but I can't fin a systemBlack color in the picker... thank you for helping me !

Comment: The text should be "System Label".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add dark mode support to your app, you should use the color set in the asset folder. By setting the appearance of color set to any and dark and after that you can set the value of colors for light mode(Any) and dark mode. you can use these colors project specifically in the color picker of a storyboard.[image]

[image]

Comment: which assets folder are you talking about? the assets.xcassets? Im net o swift and Xcode sorry for being dumb

Comment: @JGStyleSSBU yes, assets.xcassets folder. thereby doing a right-click you can create new color set.